# bootstrap 4 navbar fade in\out when scrolling in a rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to figure out how to have a top navbar in bootstrap 4 and then when the user scrolls down a little on the page have the navbar **fade in** I can currently get the navbar to show up using the below script, however, it doesn't fade in it just immediately shows up very fast and awkwardly.

```
<script>
$(document).scroll(function(e){
    var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
    if(scrollTop > 200){

        $('.navbar').removeClass('static-top').addClass('fixed-top');

    } else {
        $('.navbar').removeClass('fixed-top').addClass('static-top');
    }
});
</script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav><!--./nav-->
```

I'm looking for a navbar effect like this http://bootstraplovers.com/assan-v3.6/classic-template/html/index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.navbar').removeClass('static-top').addClass('fixed-top');
```

before calling `.removeClass()` you need to call `.toggle()` or other similar jquery effects. Refer to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

`.toggle()` would hide the navbar, so maybe you want to post your question in the relevant stackoverflow section (jquery), think about how you want to build this animation and search the jquery documentation...